# Moving Chrome cache to RAM disk

Tags: google-chrome, browser-cache, ramdisk

Let the RAM disk be created with some software, and suppose its letter is E:.

Why the following shortcut change does nothing:

> ```
> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --disk-cache-dir=“E:\chrome-cache\" --disk-cache-size=419430400
> ```

Any hints?

Comment: 1. How do you know that there's no actual change?
2. Is it possible that the quotation mark is invalid (“ instead of "), which breaks the syntax of the command? Try to replace the quotation mark and see if there's any difference.

Comment: @Catalyst You noticed the tiny little quotation mark is different, please post an answer, case solved

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like the syntax of your command broke because of an invalid quotation mark - `“` instead of `"`.
Fix this and it should work.

Comment: So called "smart quotes" are a sure sign of someone writing webpage content using Word, or another word processor, and copying the result into a webpage. I've lost count of the number of times the problem was with copy-pasting a smart quote rather than an actual problem with the command.